# How to transfer folder(which has child) from one repository to another using CMIS apche chemistry

Tags: java, cmis, opencmis, apache-chemistry

I have two repository in IBM file content management and now I want to transfer folder (which has a child ) from one repository to another and also should be transfer their child using CMIS.

Comment: What did you try? How far did you get? Where did it break?

Comment: ok,i can transfer a folder from one folder to another folder if it is  in same repository.Here i am using IBM file content management and using Apache Web Cmis API. Now i have two repository(with two difference Url,Username,password) which is located in two different place and used URL to connect them.Now i want to tranfer a folder from one repository to another repository with their child. would you like to see my code??

Answer (score 2):

The CMIS specification and Apache Chemistry do not support copying or moving between repositories with a single service or method.  An app can do that by logging into both repositories, retrieving info about a folder and its children in repository 1, then creating that folder and children in repository 2.

[1](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-cmis2/) is an example of copying a file system to a repository.  For your use case, you would retrieve folder and document properties and document content streams from the source repository instead of the file system.

Comment: you are right .I am logging into both repository one by one and create a folder(which is i am transferring ) at destination side but now problem is that i am not able to create sub folder of that folder.

Comment: What is your code for creating subfolder and what error did you get?    

An example is to insert 'Folder newSubfolder = newFolder.createFolder(properties2);' at the end of [Creating a folder](https://chemistry.apache.org/java/examples/example-create-update.html).